# How do I clone a Django model instance object and show on the Django forms?

Tags: python, django, models

So, the first part is pretty clear.

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
customer.pk = None
customer.save() # Saved a new instance. 
# But i want to modify it
```

The problem here is that i want to modify that instance, before saving. for that i have to render it on the form in HTML.

How to achieve that?

Suggestions needed.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You modify the pk after the form has been submitted.
You pass customer as instance to a CustomerForm and let the form save a new object. Something like:

```
    class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Customer

    def my_view(request):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
        customer.pk = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
            if form.is_valid():
                customer = form.save()
                return redirect('...')
        else:
            form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)
        return render(request, 'template', {'form': form})
```